# WPF DataGrid ContentPresenter Binding Errors

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm using a WPF Datagrid with DataGridTemplateColumns with comboboxes in each cell.  At startup, the output window repeats the following message and delays startup about 10 seconds.  Something related to ContentPresenter and DataContext not being set (DataItem=null).  Please help if you can.  Here is the error message:

System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

It's not technically an error, but it delays the startup nonetheless.  Here is a subset of the xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid"  
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="True" 
          IsEnabled="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
          EnableRowVirtualization="False"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          GridLinesVisibility="Vertical" 
          AreRowDetailsFrozen="True"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          HeadersVisibility="All"
          Height="750"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          DataContext="{StaticResource vm}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=CorpActionAutoPostConfigs, Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=False}">

         <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!-- selecteditembinding: source:enum, dest:JournalType -->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="JournalType" x:Name="colJournalType">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="cbJournalTypes"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=JournalTypes, IsAsync=False}" 
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GenericDataTemplate}"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=JournalTypeCode, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource JournalTypeConverter}, IsAsync=False}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

...more similar columns follow.  I feel like I need to set a Style or ControlTemplate or something but not exactly sure how to proceed.

If I use a ListView/GridView structure, these "errors" do not occur and startup is much faster.  But I would prefer to use the DataGrid.

One clue is it seems I get that error for each visible cell that is generated.  So I tried to define a style for DataGridCell, that sets the control template for each cell and includes a ContentPresenter binding with a fallback value.  Did not resolve the errors.

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="DataGridCellContentPresenter"
Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, FallbackValue=null}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

**EDIT:**

Looking at the Visual Tree, it seems the ContentPresenter I have defined in the ControlTemplate contains yet another ContentPresenter.  That ContentPresenter is nameless and I suspect is the source of the binding errors.  The parent of that ContentPresenter is the Border.  Does anyone know how to define this ContentPresenter in a ControlTemplate so I can add a fallback value?

I can't yet add a screencap of the visual tree, but here is what it looks like:

- DataGridCell

  - ContentPresenter (name=DataGridCellPresenter)

    - ContentPresenter (unnamed, Border is parent)

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you use `ListView` to present this collection do you enable user to add new content? I had similar problem and the issue was `CanUserAddRows="True"`. Try disabling this option and see if it helps. If it does then you would have to provide `Fallback` values for your bindings. HTH

Comment: Yes I've seen the binding errors caused by CanUserAddRows="True" (something about NewItemPlaceholder or something). The binding error I am experiencing is not that.  It seems the DataContext is not set when the DataGrid is being built.  A fallback value may fix this, but it is none of the bindings in my xaml.

Comment: It seems that the binding on your `Content` in the `ContentPresenter` is failing try to remove the Content Binding and use it without binding but leave the rest of the bindings i.e. `<ContentPresenter
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                    ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" 
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />` I have used the `ControlTemplate` for `Expander` and it was fine without specifying the Content property. HTH

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I removed the Content binding and the errors are still present.  That's strange, I don't quite understand how I'm getting a Content binding error if each DataGridCell is using a control template without a Content binding.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I managed a work around for this issue - if derive your own custom class from DataGridTemplateColumn you can explicitly set the FallbackValue for the Binding.

Obviously you then have to go through the XAML and replace the required elements.

```
    public sealed class DataGridTemplateColumnEx : DataGridTemplateColumn
    {
        protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
        {
            return LoadTemplateContent(false, dataItem, cell);
        }

        protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
        {
            return LoadTemplateContent(true, dataItem, cell);
        }

        private void ChooseCellTemplateAndSelector(bool isEditing, out DataTemplate template, out DataTemplateSelector templateSelector)
        {
            template = null;
            templateSelector = null;

            if (isEditing)
            {
                template = CellEditingTemplate;
                templateSelector = CellEditingTemplateSelector;
            }

            if (template == null && templateSelector == null)
            {
                template = CellTemplate;
                templateSelector = CellTemplateSelector;
            }
        }

        private FrameworkElement LoadTemplateContent(bool isEditing, object dataItem, DataGridCell cell)
        {
            ChooseCellTemplateAndSelector(isEditing, out var template, out var templateSelector);
            if (template != null || templateSelector != null)
            {
                var contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();

                var binding = new Binding
                {
                    // Explicitly setting this to NULL, stops the binding FallbackValue messages, and therefore improves perf...
                    FallbackValue = null
                };

                BindingOperations.SetBinding(contentPresenter, ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, binding);
                contentPresenter.ContentTemplate = template;
                contentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector = templateSelector;
                return contentPresenter;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```